# Rational Counting Function

Tags: code-golf, rational-numbers

Create a function that takes a natural number (starting from 0 inclusive), and returns a pair of positive integers, which are the numerator and denominator respectively.
Use the diagonal traversal. Previous-counted numbers must be skipped. (you can memorize the set of skipped values)

Diagram:

[image]

Red are skipped values

Values:

- f(0) = 1, 1
- f(1) = 2, 1
- f(2) = 1, 2
- f(3) = 1, 3
- f(4) = 3, 1 (notice the skip)
- f(5) = 4, 1
- f(6) = 3, 2
- f(7) = 2, 3
- f(8) = 1, 4
- f(9) = 1, 5
- f(10) = 5, 1 (notice the skip)

You may use the Rational data structure and their operations if they exist.
Shortest code wins.

Comment: The number of counted rational numbers in each diagonal is the totient function of that diagonal's common sum.

Comment: I know this challenge is old, but there exists a shorter answer than the accepted one, so you might want to re-accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### J, <s>41</s> 36 characters

Takes an integers and returns a vector comprising two integers. My first solution that is neither entirely tacit nor entirely explicit.

```
{3 :'~.;<`(<@|.)/.(,%+.)"0/~1+i.1+y'
```

Here is the solution with spaces inserted where appropriate:

```
{ 3 : '~. ; <`(<@|.)/. (, % +.)"0/~ 1 + i. 1 + y'
```

An explanation:

1. `x (, % +.) y`–a vector of length 2 representing the fraction with numerator `x` and denominator `y` reduced to the smallest denominator
2. `1 + i. 1 + y`–a vector of integers from `1` to `y + 1`
3. `(, % +.)"0/~ 1 + i. 1 + y`–a matrix of all reduced fractions with unreduced denominator and numerator in the range from `1` to `y + 1`.
4. `` <`(<@|.)/. y ``–an array of the oblique diagonals of matrix `y`, each other diagonal flipped
5. `~. ; y`–an array of diagonals collapsed into a vector of elements with duplicates removed
6. `x { y`–the item at position `x` in `y`
7. `(u v) y`–the same as `y u v y`. In this particular use case, `u` is `{` and `v` is `` 3 : '~. ; <`(<@|.)/. (, % +.)"0/~ 1 + i. 1 + y' ``

Comment: [30 bytes](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT8FIocJKW82o2ljBSr1OTyc2oUZPX09Vvy5Tz0i7Uv1/anJGvkKamp1Cpp6h4X8A)

Answer (score 8):

### Haskell, 78 characters

```
q(r,f)=[(r-b,b)|b<-f[1..r-1],r`gcd`b==1]
d=reverse:id:d
f=((zip[2..]d>>=q)!!)
```

Sample run:

```
> map f [0..10]
[(1,1),(2,1),(1,2),(1,3),(3,1),(4,1),(3,2),(2,3),(1,4),(1,5),(5,1)]
> f 100
(17,1)
> f 1000
(3,55)
```

---

- Edit: (100 → 87) silly me, just testing the gcd is enough!
- Edit: (87 → 85) clever trick with `cycle` and functions to alternate row order
- Edit: (85 → 82) replace `cycle` with the hand-built infinite list `d`
- Edit: (82 → 78) applied `gcd` identity as suggested by Matías

Comment: By definition, `gcd (r-b) b == gcd r b` and you can shave off four more characters.

Answer (score 3):

### Python, 144 chars

```
def F(i):
 r,d,z=[1],1,[]
 while z[:i]==z:z+=[(x,y)for x,y in zip(r[::d],r[::-d])if all(x%j+y%j for j in r[1:])];d=-d;r+=[r[-1]+1]
 return z[i]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby 1.9, <strike>109</strike> 106

```
F=->n{x=y=d=1
e=0
n.times{(x+=d).gcd(y+=e)>1&&redo
x<2?d<0?d=0:(d,e=1,-1):y<2?e<0?e=0:(d,e=-1,1):0}
[x,y]}
```

Answer (score 2):

## OCaml + Batteries, <strike>182</strike> 168 characters

This is what would be natural in Haskell but is only barely possible in OCaml:

```
open LazyList
let rec r(i,j)=lazy(let a,b=if(i+j)mod 2=0then i,j else j,i in
Cons((a,b),filter(fun(c,d)->a*d<>c*b)(r(if j=1 then 1,i+1else i+1,j-1))))
let f=nth(r(1,1))
```

*Edit:* The diagonal is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 75 bytes

```perl6
{(({|(1…($+=2)…1)}…*)Z/(1,{|(1…(($||=1)+=2)…1)}…*)).unique[$_]}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##bY/LToQwFIb3fYqzaOR0YKjlMl4mGN9BV47GjNCJRAZwAJMJkPg0PpgvgqdM3RgXbb70/P36t9aHYjV1jYaPlZ@uGdsf4SytMg3J1CP2A6rvzy/kbhIIAiVG2hfiQaLyfofIhyFR4k9E@F2Zv3d6w5@fxom0t61uWkigyEvd@PttfQ394KfV/gXlY@ZK4d1JcAAd8BfgCAc4SDkyZsrd09U1q4ttCe7soaa76mCdyxtA4HlZd63Hy87jmTarSUFAzwDyZplpXRdHMD/DU1J4gBSWFCSc42ycdnguqKPyQLEdKsPBiQN7HhCHlkPiyHBIGcCyavNUQ/uqoXnLa0HT2Eyjk2Flk8ZwYc3GcGltEfGV5di8PleJ/1X/AA)

This basically generates the entire sequence of rational values, only stopping once the indexed value is generated.

(Based on [my golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166970) to another challenge.)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit parameter $_

  (
      ( # sequence of numerators

        {
          |( # slip into outer sequence (flatten)

            1      # start at one
            …
            (
              $    # state variable
              += 2 # increment it by two each time this block is called
            )
            …
            1      # finish at one
          )

        }
        … * # never stop generating values
      )


    Z/   # zip using &infix:« /  » (generates Rats)


      ( # sequence of denominators

        1,  # start with an extra one

        {
          |( # slip into outer sequence (flatten)

            1
            …
            (
              ( $ ||= 1 ) # state variable that starts with 1 (rather than 0)
              += 2        # increment it by two each time this is called
            )
            …
            1
          )
        }
        … * # never stop generating values
      )


  ).unique                # get only the unique values
  .[ $_ ]                 # index into the sequence
}
```

---

`({1…($+=2)…1}…*)` generates the infinite sequence of numerators (`|(…)` is used above to flatten)

```perl6
(1 2 1)
(1 2 3 4 3 2 1)
(1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1)
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1)
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1)
…
```

`(1,{1…(($||=1)+=2)…1}…*)` generates the infinite sequence of denominators

```perl6
1
(1 2 3 2 1)
(1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1)
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 6 5 4 3 2 1)
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1)
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1)
…
```