# Number the positive rationals

Tags: code-golf, rational-numbers

The positive rational numbers can be shown to be numerable with the following process:

1. Zero has the ordinal 0
2. Arrange the other numbers in a grid so that row a, column b contains a/b
3. Plot a diagonal zig-zag top right to bottom left
4. Keep a running tally of the unique numbers encountered along the zig-zag

Here's a picture of the zig-zag:

[image: Start at 1/1, initial move right]

So, the numbers encountered are, in order

```
1/1, 2/1, 1/2, 1/3, 2/2, 3/1, 4/1, 3/2, 2/3, 1/4, 1/5, 2/4, 3/3, 4/2, 5/1, 6/1, 5/2, 4/3, 3/4, 2/5, 1/6, 1/7, 2/6, 3/5, 4/4, 5/3 ...
```

And the simplified, unique numbers encountered are

```
1, 2, 1/2, 1/3, 3, 4, 3/2, 2/3, 1/4, 1/5, 5, 6, 5/2, 4/3, 3/4, 2/5, 1/6, 1/7, 3/5, 5/3, ...
```

## Challenge:

- Given *two* greater-than-zero integers **p** and **q**, output the **ordinal number** of p/q
- p and q are not necessarily co-prime
- Shortest code wins
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default?noredirect=1&lq=1) are prohibited

### Test cases:

Here are the first 24 rational numbers encountered, and the desired output for each:

```
1/1: 1
2/1: 2
1/2: 3
1/3: 4
2/2: 1
3/1: 5
4/1: 6
3/2: 7
2/3: 8
1/4: 9
1/5: 10
2/4: 3
3/3: 1
4/2: 2
5/1: 11
6/1: 12
5/2: 13
4/3: 14
3/4: 15
2/5: 16
1/6: 17
1/7: 18
2/6: 4
3/5: 19
```

And, for further test cases, here are the 200 first positive rational numbers in order:

```
1, 2, 1/2, 1/3, 3, 4, 3/2, 2/3, 1/4, 1/5, 
5, 6, 5/2, 4/3, 3/4, 2/5, 1/6, 1/7, 3/5, 5/3, 
7, 8, 7/2, 5/4, 4/5, 2/7, 1/8, 1/9, 3/7, 7/3, 
9, 10, 9/2, 8/3, 7/4, 6/5, 5/6, 4/7, 3/8, 2/9, 
1/10, 1/11, 5/7, 7/5, 11, 12, 11/2, 10/3, 9/4, 8/5, 
7/6, 6/7, 5/8, 4/9, 3/10, 2/11, 1/12, 1/13, 3/11, 5/9, 
9/5, 11/3, 13, 14, 13/2, 11/4, 8/7, 7/8, 4/11, 2/13, 
1/14, 1/15, 3/13, 5/11, 7/9, 9/7, 11/5, 13/3, 15, 16, 
15/2, 14/3, 13/4, 12/5, 11/6, 10/7, 9/8, 8/9, 7/10, 6/11, 
5/12, 4/13, 3/14, 2/15, 1/16, 1/17, 5/13, 7/11, 11/7, 13/5, 
17, 18, 17/2, 16/3, 15/4, 14/5, 13/6, 12/7, 11/8, 10/9, 
9/10, 8/11, 7/12, 6/13, 5/14, 4/15, 3/16, 2/17, 1/18, 1/19, 
3/17, 7/13, 9/11, 11/9, 13/7, 17/3, 19, 20, 19/2, 17/4, 
16/5, 13/8, 11/10, 10/11, 8/13, 5/16, 4/17, 2/19, 1/20, 1/21, 
3/19, 5/17, 7/15, 9/13, 13/9, 15/7, 17/5, 19/3, 21, 22, 
21/2, 20/3, 19/4, 18/5, 17/6, 16/7, 15/8, 14/9, 13/10, 12/11, 
11/12, 10/13, 9/14, 8/15, 7/16, 6/17, 5/18, 4/19, 3/20, 2/21, 
1/22, 1/23, 5/19, 7/17, 11/13, 13/11, 17/7, 19/5, 23, 24, 
23/2, 22/3, 21/4, 19/6, 18/7, 17/8, 16/9, 14/11, 13/12, 12/13, 
11/14, 9/16, 8/17, 7/18, 6/19, 4/21, 3/22, 2/23, 1/24, 1/25
```

Shout out to the [inverse question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2497/rational-counting-function?rq=1), where the first move is down so you can't use the answers to generate additional test cases.

Comment: I wonder if there are alternative numbering schemes that make for shorter code.

Comment: Numerators of fractions: http://oeis.org/A157807 denominators: http://oeis.org/A157813 No matches for ordinal sequence: http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C1%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%2C3&sort=&language=&go=Search

Comment: i see. you have to reduce the fraction and then count. its not the zig-zag only

Comment: Related: [Zigzagify a Matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75587/zigzagify-a-matrix) and [Reconstruct a zigzagified matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75588/reconstruct-a-zigzagified-matrix).

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>21</s>  20 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>Probably beatable by a number of bytes using some clever mathematics...</sup>

```
:g/
ÇµSRRUĖ€UÐeẎÇ€Qi
```

A monadic link accepting a list of `[p,q]` which returns the natural number assigned to `p/q`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98qXZ/rcPuhrcFBQaFHpj1qWhN6eELqw119h9uB7MDM////RxvpmMUCAA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98qXZ/rcPuhrcFBQaFHpj1qWhN6eELqw119h9uB7MBMrqOTHu6cAWQe3QMWyQLiRw1zFHTtFB41zI38//9/dLShjmGsTrQRmDTUMQKTxmARENsYLG4CJo3BIkZgWUMdEzBpChYxAcsag1WC1JiC1ZuBSVOwiAlY1his0gisy1DHDEyag0XMwLKmsbEA).

#### How?

First note that the **N<sup>th</sup>** diagonal encountered contains all of the grid's rational numbers for which the sum of the numerator and denominator equals **N+1**, so given a function which reduces a `[p,q]` pair to simplest form (`[p/gcd(p,q),q/gcd(p,q)]`) we can build the diagonals as far as need be*, reduce all the entries, de-duplicate and find the index of the simplified input.

* actually one further here to save a byte

```
:g/ - Link 1, simplify a pair: list of integers, [a, b]
  / - reduce using:
 g  - Greatest Common Divisor -> gcd(a, b)
:   - integer division (vectorises) -> [a/gcd(a,b), b/gcd(a,b)]

ÇµSRRUĖ€UÐeẎÇ€Qi - Main Link: list of integers, [p, q]
Ç                - call last Link as a monad (simplify)
 µ               - start a new monadic chain (call that V)
  S              - sum -> the diagonal V will be in plus one
   R             - range -> [1,2,3,...,diag(V)+1]
    R            - range (vectorises) -> [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],...,[1,2,3,...,diag(V)+1]]
     U           - reverse each       -> [[1],[2,1],[3,2,1],[diag(V)+1,...,3,2,1]]
      Ė€         - enumerate €ach     -> [[[1,1]],[[1,2],[2,1]],[[1,3],[2,2],[3,1]],[[1,diag(V)+1],...,[diag(V)-1,3],[diag(V),2],[diag(V)+1,1]]]
         Ðe      - apply only to the even indexed items:
        U        -   reverse each     -> [[[1,1]],[[2,1],[1,2]],[[1,3],[2,2],[3,1]],[[4,1],[3,2],[2,3],[1,4]],...]
           Ẏ     - tighten            -> [[1,1],[2,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,2],[3,1],[4,1],[3,2],[2,3],[1,4],...]
            Ç€   - for €ach: call last Link as a monad (simplify each)
                 -                    -> [[1,1],[2,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,1],[3,1],[4,1],[3,2],[2,3],[1,4],...]
              Q  - de-duplicate       -> [[1,1],[2,1],[1,2],[1,3],[3,1],[4,1],[3,2],[2,3],[1,4],...]
               i - index of V in that list
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>94</s>  90 bytes

```perl6
->\p,\q{(({|(1…($+=2)…1)}…*)Z/(1,{|(1…(($||=1)+=2)…1)}…*)).unique.first(p/q,:k)+1}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##XY9NTsMwEIX3PsWospBN3Bjnx21TpeIQrFA3JXGliDR1mhSB2kqchkuw4yhcJMxE/Ehs8uL3vTcee3eo7XDsHDzZsFgytnuBq2JfOsiH6Wrt1bo9CXE6C/P5@iZ4kEcSf4y84Pda3mth1A8U/HzOjfwXkeGxqdqjC7fVoeuF163KHmVgLgPedNu7rocc6qpx3cd7WOx3D0Kvy0BLXIW2usPAkvl600AwptHf7g/fzekKBHCveKu4e/au6F0JEk4MoOqAniFGKhX8cgUT7jVvsz9rwi6D0SYDwyKSiBkdZRCjxBkkaEbEYmIpS0gsntCcIcPIHJNJBguUFJM36CbUjwkabEQ0NB2vMMyOSmcaGyOmVIJpLJkUyzTE4jCLOkOdoc7Rt7RNPOLFFw)

```perl6
{(({|(1…($+=2)…1)}…*)Z/(1,{|(1…(($||=1)+=2)…1)}…*)).unique.first($^p/$^q):k+1}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##XY9dSsNAFIXfZxWXMsiMiYmTn0mbEnERPokUNJ1CMG2TJhWlLbgaN@GbS3Ej8dzgD/iSkznfOXfuNG5X22HfOXqyQTkXYv1CZ@V26agYDkodjsp8vr4p6RWRxo/RJ3zP9W2ojP8DlTweC6P/RXSw31Tt3gWratf1Si6aUC5anT965jTgluvedT0VVFcb1328B@V2/aDCu6UXaqzBG90gMBdNfb8hb0zDX213382LK1IkG1@2vnTPjSt7tyRNB0FUdcRPUCPVPv1ynyYSa7T5nzURp8GEJicjIpZImDDKKYbEOSUwI2Yxs1QkLBYnmBkYIlMkk5xmkBTJS7gJ92OGBo2Ih6bjFUbYUfnMY2NgTiVIo2RSlHmIxTALzaAZdArf8jbxiGdf)

This basically generates the entire sequence of values, and stops when it finds a match.

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with placeholder parameters $p,$q

  (
      ( # sequence of numerators

        {
          |( # slip into outer sequence (flatten)

            1      # start at one
            …
            (
              $    # state variable
              += 2 # increment it by two each time this block is called
            )
            …
            1      # finish at one
          )

        }
        … * # never stop generating values
      )


    Z/   # zip using &infix:« /  » (generates Rats)


      ( # sequence of denominators

        1,  # start with an extra one

        {
          |( # slip into outer sequence (flatten)

            1
            …
            (
              ( $ ||= 1 ) # state variable that starts with 1 (rather than 0)
              += 2        # increment it by two each time this is called
            )
            …
            1
          )
        }
        … * # never stop generating values
      )


  ).unique            # get only the unique values
  .first( $^p / $^q ) # find the first one that matches the input
  :k                  # get the index instead (0 based)
  + 1                 # add one               (1 based)
}
```

---

`({1…($+=2)…1}…*)` generates the infinite sequence of numerators (`|(…)` is used above to flatten)

```perl6
(1 2 1)
(1 2 3 4 3 2 1)
(1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1)
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1)
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1)
…
```

`(1,{1…(($||=1)+=2)…1}…*)` generates the infinite sequence of denominators

```perl6
1
(1 2 3 2 1)
(1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1)
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 6 5 4 3 2 1)
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1)
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1)
…
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <del>157</del>, <del>146</del>, <del>140</del>, 133 bytes

```python
def f(p,q):a=[(i+i-abs(j-i-i))/(abs(j-i-i+.5)+.5)for i in range(p+q)for j in range(4*i)];return sorted(set(a),key=a.index).index(p/q)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZHdboQgEIXvfYq5hIq7XfGv2/gkxgsbscs2QQSadJ/eMjjdGgxnjt8Mw2gf4bYaue@zWmBhVmz8OvUD07kupg/P7oUuNOdn9gzyU83xXVYHGrQBN5lPxWy@Jev@b1Uvmo/vToVvZ8CvLqiZeRXYxMWXevTTSZtZ/fBjY/a88T0oH3w/ZMNFAK5RZEOZZIkSdwGSpBRQEVASKxNbo6ySbMiNQEtsjDqqEJk3knXEX4mo6AyZ4AtVK6mJ@mgt2c2h/3xsQxKOmRVVwV5qKo7pDR2K6S3pNuqOmIZuJg889VhiwQhVnRzHDEdtBWwCnPI48jS5awbxsU6bwJ5fRfqvsPG@jxHffwE)

won 11 bytes thanks to [Jonathan Frech](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73111/jonathan-frech)

won 6 more bytes and then 7 thanks to [Chas Brown](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69880/chas-brown)

Comment: [146 bytes](https://tio.run/##RZHbboMwDIbveQpfxhDaQsJhnfIkiItMhS2VRjlN2nh5Fgevk0D8tj8fsMef9eMxqH2/dT30YpSTtEYgXiPoHzM4cAPMdnjvxKf9pjAmGQVD9P4f1bHD62aES1xq3xZxT13qEM/iaSSnAul9tYkRm8T4EsdiowoWI5i79Wv28uSGW@cbnSfc125ZF9NETSaBnlZGTR5kTpK@EhRLJUEzkDOrAluQ1EGW7PVAxay3aq7gmReWhccvTGjuoQKccbWchyiO0YK7PPSfn8ZQjFOm5io0S8HFKb3kppResa68rpkp@c/UgYcZcyroIV2rto3oFqOESfo1LrTRsDm6EsA4u2EVz6gMR4YJjfEW7r8).

Comment: [140 bytes](https://tio.run/##RZHbcoQgDIbvfQouoeJuFTx0Oz6J4wUdsct2igp0ZvfpLcF06@DwJ/kSQlgf4bpYse@TnslMV76xi@oHanJTqA9Pb4UpDGNn@jTyU83gnxdHDDGWOGU/Nf1W95Sdlyly@4/IF8PGd6fDj7PELy7oiXodqGL8Sz96dTJ20nd2bHQ9b2wP2gffD9lQcgJr5NlQJVmBhJ0TgVJwIhGokBWJrUHKJBv0RqBFNlodVojMG8o64q9ISDxDJLjEahU2UR@tJXdz6D8/tCEQh0yJVaCXGotDeoOHQnqLuo26Q6bBm4kDTz1WUDBCshPjmMGoV042Tpz2MPI0uUtG4rc6YwN9Rnl6XrKxvo8W238B).

Comment: @bobrobbob: Welcome to PPCG! I'm not quite sure how your algorithm works (although it clearly does); but experimentally, it seems you can save some more bytes by replacing `range(max(p,q)+1)` with `range(p+q)`.

Comment: You can save some more bytes by using `{*a}` instead of `set(a)`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>157</s> <s>144</s> <s>137</s> <s>134</s> <s>126</s> 125 bytes

```python
def f(p,q):a=[((j-i)/(i+1.))**(j%-2|1)for j in range(p-~q)for i in range(j)];return-~sorted(set(a),key=a.index).index(p*1./q)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZHdaoQwEIWv26fIjZjYqDXxZ3eLTyJeCMY2FqJGd9mFsq9uM3FKITAnh2/OTMj82L4mI/a9VwMZ6MwXdunqhtIx1iyl@i1LGIsiOgax@MnYMFkyEm2I7cynonP8XLyn/72RtR9WbVdr4uc62U31dFUb7Rj/Vo@6S7Tp1Z0dhc5RlqQL2yHDzeY3yGmajBM4LSeN8FKAhMqJRCk5yREQyErPFiBzL0t0HVAh624nTHDMGWXh8HckcpwhPZxhmsAlimM1b5eH/vNhDYk4dOaYArsUGA7tJQ6F9gp15fQJmRJfJg/83LaX15fZarORMFjTYA0D/1H8xsM65Mev7fsv)

4 bytes saved due to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder);
1 byte from [Jonathon Frech](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73111/jonathan-frech).

As noted by Mr. Xcoder, we can do a bit better in Python 3 since, amongst other things, integer division defaults to float results, and we can more easily unpack `list`s:

#### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 117 bytes

```python
def f(p,q):a=[((j-i)/-~i)**(j%-2|1)for j in range(p-~q)for i in range(j)];return-~sorted({*a},key=a.index).index(p/q)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZHdaoQwEIWv26fIjZhIslbjz@4Wn0S8EIxtLESNdtmlra9uM3FKITAnh2/OTMj0WN9HI/e9Uz3p6cRndm2rmtJBaBaLTbMookMg0u@E9aMlA9GG2Na8KTqJbfae/vcG1rxatX5aI7ZltKvq6FfU/vAP9ajakzadurOj0Cme2Q7tbia/QURdJ5zAaTipUy9TkFA5kSglJxkCKbLSsznIzMsCXQeUyLrbGRMcc0GZO/wFiQxnSA8nmJbiEvmxmreLQ//5sIZEHDozTIFdcgyH9gKHQnuJunT6jEyBL5MHfmma6/PTZLVZaRgscbCEgf8gfuNhFfLjt9i@/wI)

Comment: [128 bytes (-6)](https://tio.run/##RZBNboMwEIXXzSm8QdjEQG3@kqg5CWVBQ0iNijEGRa1U9erU40xVyZLfPH3zZmzztb5PWm79@XX7aMe3riWGz6ea0iFWLKVqLxLGoogOQSy/BesnSwaiNLGtvl2piX9m76l/b2CqJ7dLB70cUl5kkyjdXT@piUSSzmzX22kkvW0vq5r0QtRoJrtGGwS56fwOYXUtOIHTcFJLLyVIuDnJUGac5AhIZDPPFiBzL0t0HVAh66oDJjjmiLJw@DMSOc7IPCwwTeISxWM1b5cP/efDGhni0JljCuxSYDi0lzgU2ivUldMHZEp8WfbAj01z2j0Zq/RKwmBJgyUMqPssxu88PIe898VebNsv) by swapping the fraction and using `**(j%-2|1)` and `p-~q`.

Comment: @Mr. Xcoder: You're all about the negative modulo today! :) I think I still need the `+1` at the end, since `1,1` 'must' give `1`, not `0`.

Comment: [125 bytes](https://tio.run/##RZHdaoQwEIWv26fIjZjYUVfjz@6WfRLxQmrcRmiM0S4tFF/dJnFKITAnh2/OTIj@Xt8nle97LwYyUA0zu3a3htIxli/JiaXxJlkU0THYsp@MDZMhI5GKmE7dBdXxNntP/nsja1@NWD@NirdlMqvo6SJW2jF4@9DQJVL14osdheooS9KZ7S7DzoaHy2maDIg7LZAm9zJ30lUgHCUHUiCQI8s9WzpZeFmha4EaWXs7Y4JlLihLi5@QKHAG93CGaTkuUR6rebs69J/v1uCIu84CU9wuJYa79gqHuvYadW31GZkKX8YP/NK21@cnbaRaSRgsabCEgf8oeEB4C@H4tX3/BQ).

Comment: [124 bytes](https://tio.run/##RZHdasQgEIWv26fwpqCpZjean90tfZKQi9CYrYEakw3LFkpe3To6pSDM8fDNmRHd9/Y5W@n9oEcyUscXdunfW0onYV7zIzuI3bAso9OLkD8FG@eVTMRYsvb2qqkT@xI98@9NrHtzq7Gb2G/zuumB3vRGe8Y/vhzvc2MH/WCpUJcV@WFhHiLCaH6HmLYtOIHTcdLKKCVIqJwolIqTEgGJrIpsBbKMskY3AA2y4XbChMCcUVYBPyJR4gwV4QLTJC5RpdWiXSf958MaCnHoLDEFdqkwHNprHArtDeom6BMyNb5MJfzcdZfnp/Q13v8C) :) Yeah the negative modulo turns out to be really helpful!

Comment: Actually [117 bytes in Python 3](https://tio.run/##RZHdaoQwEIWv26fIjZhIslbjz@4Wn0S8EIxtLESNdtmlra9uM3FKITAnh2/OTMj0WN9HI/e9Uz3p6cRndm2rmtJBaBaLTbMookMg0u@E9aMlA9GG2Na8KTqJbfae/vcG1rxatX5aI7ZltKvq6FfU/vAP9ajakzadurOj0Cme2Q7tbia/QURdJ5zAaTipUy9TkFA5kSglJxkCKbLSsznIzMsCXQeUyLrbGRMcc0GZO/wFiQxnSA8nmJbiEvmxmreLQ//5sIZEHDozTIFdcgyH9gKHQnuJunT6jEyBL5MHfmma6/PTZLVZaRgscbCEgf8gfuNhFfLjt9i@/wI)

Comment: I'm always a bit reticent to switch from 2.7 to 3.x when golfing an answer - I admit, I'm a prig! :).

Answer (score 2):

## J, <strike>41</strike>, <strike>35</strike>, 30 bytes

*-11 bytes thanks to FrownyFrog*

```
%i.~0~.@,@,[:]`|./.[:%/~1+i.@*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZVPaxtBDMXv/hRDISRunM1Knr@GgKHQU0@9hkIhdah7aQ899FD81d3uTvTT7sEg2zPSe09Pmh/Xd8Pta3g6hNuwC2M4/P88DOHD508frzfn4TJehuPuuHs@fPn6d3gcng83jxe5Pw/H99ftZnP68@v08vv07WkIdxJeg2x34U4tmH5RC/ZTsLe/ogV7O6N2ZjocLUhTkOxwtiDZrbjMHC1PsuvZgmJnSDjfKpawWlAsc7KE0W6p5ZkSVguaZS52fc7cEGG0qFnquiwfjRjIslUFdLXyzarKSIQgAOj06Yd4Q7wj4xJoNFTJUmRDVSx7NVQQ7hgUDHNB@i3ecBA2K@gIe8vxhWAMwRkiS4iwBJC46zCQ4CBJ4NhjJloNokKlRPWeDfcJ9hP8J3HFIaK3M8zoXaxYNTINE474G7UEhy@0xOOCyQWXC90St7d3voCz38X9gv0F/89sXYEIW9cnw9bVq7BF2s6trnTv3PK6K4zbomcZvoyeMHviXsQW4uPnzBuYCyw7N@ZUmVNhUIUBlbxiXn3CRh9y3yTOiWHuCBXU8ygyxcoy7P@mNacEJ/daozfOKYF/Pqe@k9kByg7QcaVCxAnujgz3QrWKE1zVNxV0rbr4qll0hUkWto2wbhYO9vmmy8rGUX9g2DjqqvtcuTMX0ol7vcC/73g2kbKJ1N8oXSkbuZvRzntR0a75ZvPV9ibOYm353mpoUtc@qOjUTB13jvKOKntQ2YOapvf65fvP6et9OA86jtvwcAj2hm@u/wA)

## original 41 bytes post with explanation

```
%>:@i.~[:([:~.@;[:<@|.`</.%"1 0)~(1+i.@*)
```

### ungolfed

```
% >:@i.~ [: ([: ~.@; [: <@|.`</. %"1 0)~ 1 + i.@*
```

### explanation

```
                  +
                  | Everything to the right of this
                  | calculates the list
p (left arg)      |                                      create the
divided by q      |                                      diagonals.  yes,
      (right)     |                                     +this is a         +create this list
   |              |        ++ finally rmv ^alternately  |primitive ADVERB  |1..(p*q), and pass
   |   + the index          | the boxes,  |box, or      |in J              |it as both the left
   |   | of that  |         | and remove  |reverse and  |                  |and right arg to the
   |   | in the   |         | any dups    |box, each    |                  |middle verb, where each
   |   | list on  |         |             |diagonal     |                  |element will divide the
   |   | the right|         |             |             |       +----------+entire list, producing
   |   | plus 1   |         |             |             |       |          |the undiagonalized grid
   |   |          |         |             |             |       |          |
   |   |          |         |             |             |       |          |
   |   |          +         |             |             |       |          |
  ┌+┬──|──────────┬─────────|─────────────|─────────────|───────|──────────|─────────────┐
  │%│┌─+───────┬─┐│┌──┬─────|─────────────|─────────────|───────|────────┬─|────────────┐│
  │ ││┌──┬─┬──┐│~│││[:│┌────|─────────────|─────────────|───────|─────┬─┐│┌+┬─┬────────┐││
  │ │││>:│@│i.││ │││  ││┌──┬|───────┬─────|─────────────|───────|────┐│~│││1│+│┌──┬─┬─┐│││
  │ ││└──┴─┴──┘│ │││  │││[:│+──┬─┬─┐│┌──┬─|─────────────|─┬─────|───┐││ │││ │ ││i.│@│*││││
  │ │└─────────┴─┘││  │││  ││~.│@│;│││[:│┌|───────────┬─+┐│┌─┬─┬+──┐│││ │││ │ │└──┴─┴─┘│││
  │ │             ││  │││  │└──┴─┴─┘││  ││+────────┬─┐│/.│││%│"│1 0││││ ││└─┴─┴────────┘││
  │ │             ││  │││  │        ││  │││┌─┬─┬──┐│<││  ││└─┴─┴───┘│││ ││              ││
  │ │             ││  │││  │        ││  ││││<│@│|.││ ││  ││         │││ ││              ││
  │ │             ││  │││  │        ││  │││└─┴─┴──┘│ ││  ││         │││ ││              ││
  │ │             ││  │││  │        ││  ││└────────┴─┘│  ││         │││ ││              ││
  │ │             ││  │││  │        ││  │└────────────┴──┘│         │││ ││              ││
  │ │             ││  │││  │        │└──┴─────────────────┴─────────┘││ ││              ││
  │ │             ││  ││└──┴────────┴────────────────────────────────┘│ ││              ││
  │ │             ││  │└──────────────────────────────────────────────┴─┘│              ││
  │ │             │└──┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────┘│
  └─┴─────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZUxbxsxDIX3/AohQBC7Sa5HWtJJ16QwUKBTpq5eCqQO6i7t0KFD4b/u9k7hx7vBAG1L5HuPj9SPy3V3@xqexnAb7kMfxv@fhy58@vL8@XLzcdyfuvNh3BzGc7f/cBgf93@7r4/vu5trCf32vJG7U7d/t71sr66Of34dX34fvz11YSPhNcj2PmzUgukXtWA3BTv7K1qwszNqZ6bD0YI0BckOZwuS3YrLzNHyJLueLRjsDAnnW4MlLBYMljlZwmi31PJMCYsF1TIPdn3OXBGht6ha6rIsH40YyLJVBXSx8tWqSk@EIABo9OmHeEO8I/0SaDRUyVJkQzVY9mKoINwwKBjmgvRbvOEgrFbQEbaW4wvBGIIzRJYQYQkgcddhIMFBksCxw0y0GkQDlRLVWzbcJ9hP8J/EFYeI3s4wo/dgxYqRqZiwx9@oJTh8oSUeF0wuuFzolri9vfMDONtd3C/YX/D/zNYViLB1fTJsXb0CW6Rt3MpK98Ytr7vCuC16luHL6AmzJ@5FbCE@fs68gnmAZePGnCpzKgyqMKCSV8yLT1jvQ@6bxDkxzA2hgnoeRaZYWYbt37TmlODkXqv0xjkl8M/n1HcyO0DZAdqvVIg4wd2R4T5QreAEV/VNBV2rLr5qFl1hkoVtI6ybhYN9vumysnHUHxg2jrrqPlfuzIV04l4f4N92PJtI2UTqb5SulI3czWjnvShoV32z@Wp7E2extnxvVTQpax8UdKqmjjtHeUeVPajsQU3Te/3y/ef09S6cOu37bXgYg73hV5d/)

Comment: 35: ``1+~.@;@([:<@|.`</.%~/~)@(1+i.@*)i.%``

Comment: thank you, very nice!  i will update it fully later since it will require redoing the explanation...

Comment: And 30: ``%i.~0~.@,@,[:]`|./.[:%/~1+i.@*``

Comment: that’s clever, use 0 and ~. to avoid the boxing and the increment, i love it

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 121 bytes

```py
import math
def o(x,y):
 p=q=n=1
 while x*q!=p*y:a=p+q&1;p+=1+a*~-~-(p<2);q+=1-~-a*~-~-(q<2);n+=math.gcd(p,q)<2
 return n
```

Answer (score 2):

## Rust, 244 bytes

I created a simple formula to find the "plain" ordinal of a "plain" zigzag, without the constraints of the puzzle, using triangular numbers formulas:
https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/triangular-numbers.html . This was modified with modulo 2 to account for the zig-zags flipping their direction each diagonal row in the puzzle. This is function h()

Then for the main trick of this puzzle: how to 'not count' certain repeating values, like 3/3 vs 1/1, 4/2 vs 2/1, in the zig-zag trail. I ran the 1-200 examples, and noticed the difference between a plain zig-zag triangular counter, and the one the puzzle wishes for, has a pattern. The pattern of "missing" numbers is 5, 12, 13, 14, 23, etc, which resulted in a hit in the OEIS. It is one described by Robert A Stump, at https://oeis.org/A076537 , in order to "deduplicate" numbers like 3/3, 4/2, and 1/1, you can check whether GCD>1 for the x,y of all "previous" ordinals in the zigzag. This is the 'for' loops and g() which is the gcd.

I guess with some builtin gcd it would have been shorter, but I kind of couldn't find one very easily (im kind of new at Rust and Integer confused me), and I like the fact that this one uses straight up integer arithmetic, and no builtins or libraries of any kind.

```
fn f(x:i64,y:i64)->i64 {
        fn h(x:i64,y:i64)->i64 {let s=x+y;(s*s-3*s+4)/2-1+(s+1)%2*x+s%2*y}
        fn g(x:i64,y:i64)->i64 {if x==0 {y} else {g(y%x,x)}}
        let mut a=h(x,y);
        for i in 1..x+y {for j in 1..y+x {if h(i,j)<h(x,y) && g(i,j)>1 {a-=1;}}}
        a
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 86 bytes

Takes input in currying syntax `(p)(q)`.

```javascript
p=>q=>(g=x=>x*y?x*q-y*p?g(x+d,g[x/=y]=g[x]||++n,y-=d):n:g(x+!~d,y+=!~(d=-d)))(d=n=y=1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDJasMwEIbveYrJSVIst/WeGMaml0JpoQ9QcgiRY1qCd4oFIa/uSnaaKRjkT/8yY38ffg79sftqBreqVTGdcGowazHjJY6YjRudj5vW1ZsmL/noKFl@jo@o92jO/eXiOJXULiqRVqnV11cltYPrK1foKiGEOSvU6IlpKPoBEHgjoZXQCcAMjnXV1@fi4VyXnDXIwAEjs3Z@My7muhkz5qI3yRNvBG/FDRE6yIF9vDFIgb08v74zsVrZIdyTYB@xkD@TL@6auQiIAgkhOX3KBXMuulE4U0yacSaUMxdb6jTmHVFkok9kDWl8MAc9GuHTotHyEX9ivOA/1a4aUNQWhdRr941oqG2LaSXblhAmBrdkjumXBEt0J6Zf)

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 79 bytes

```
a=(p,q)=>p*q==1?1:1+((p+q)%2?q==1?a(p-1,q):a(p+1,q-1):p==1?a(p,q-1):a(p-1,q+1))
```

(I am new to code golfing, so this can probably be improved easily)

### Explanation

```
let a = (p, q) => p * q == 1 // If they are both 1
    ? 1
    // Do a recursive call and increment the result by 1
    : 1 + (
        (p + q) % 2 // If on an even-numbered diagonal
        ? q == 1 // If at the beginning of the diagonal
            ? a(p - 1, q) // Go to previous diagonal
            : a(p + 1, q - 1) // Go one back
        : p == 1 // rougly the same
            ? a(p, q - 1)
            : a(p - 1, q + 1)
    )
```

Comment: `(3,5)` should result in `19` (not `24`) since `(1,1)==(2,2)==(3,3)`, `(2,4)==(1,2)`, `(4,2)==(2,1)` and `(2,6)==(1,3)`. (i.e. `(2,2)` should result in `1` not `5`, etc...)